# How do you tell systemd that a target is satisfied with one of any requirements?

Tags: linux, systemd

How do you tell `systemd` that a requirement is satisfied with one of any instance from a list of instances?

Say that I have a target called `main_target.target` and a service template called `serv@.service`. During normal operation, the only instances of `serv@.service` that exist are:

- `serv@ex1`
- `serv@ex2`
- `serv@ex3`

Only *one* of those instances exist at any given time, and I want to tell `main_target.target` that it's satisfied whenever *any* of the three instances exist.

Intuitively, I'd like something similar to SMF's `require_any` tag, but I haven't been able to find anything like that in any of the `systemd` documentation.

Note 1: I know that I can make `serv@ex1`, `serv@ex2`, `serv@ex3` and mutually exclusive  with the `Conflicts=` directive.

Note 2: I also know that I can use the `Before=` and `After=` directives to tier the three instances to start in a certain order.

Comment: What do you mean by "satisfy a target"? Normal targets are just a way to group together units, when the target is run it doesn't really care if a service succeeds or not, that's the service's responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you can make the services mutually exclusive with the `Conflicts=` directive. The `systemd` targets are only a method for grouping together units, they do not have complex dependency options.

[systemd.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#)

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".target" encodes information about a target unit of systemd, which is used for grouping units and as well-known synchronization points during start-up.
>
> This unit type has no specific options. See systemd.unit(5) for the common options of all unit configuration files. The common configuration items are configured in the generic [Unit] and [Install] sections. A separate [Target] section does not exist, since no target-specific options may be configured.

[systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) for reference.

You can only use directives included in `systemd.unit`, and it does not include a method for starting only one of multiple services.